# Apply CSS Styling to PHP output

Tags: php, mysql, css

The following displays HTML results from the database field "Never". I am trying to apply CSS styling to the output.

**Here's what I have...**

```
echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Never']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
```

**Here's what I've tried...**

```
echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['<div id="nevermsg">'Never'</div>]."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
```

**Here's my CSS...**

```
#nevermsg { color: red; }
```

...but it's not applying properly. I am receiving a syntax error and a headache. Am I putting this in the wrong spot?

The `$results` variable is not being filled.

Edit: Code Added

**Here's my connection...**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "jpcso_compliance", "abc*123") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server
        root - username
        third is your password

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

    mysql_select_db("jpcsolut_compliance") or die(mysql_error());
    /* jpcsolut_webfro_HS is the name of database we've created */
?>
```

**There is no other HTML formatting for the output, other than what is right here...**

```
<div id="title">
<p><h1>Database Search Results</h1></p></div>
<br />
<div id="main_inner">


<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 2;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Compliance
            WHERE (`Question` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Sample Response / Must` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Must` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Can` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Never` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Tags` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
        // IllegitimateHighSchools is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p><strong><u><h2>Question:</u>&nbsp;".$results['Question']."".$results['text']."</h2></u></strong></p><br />";

                echo "<p><strong>Sample Response / Must:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Sample Response / Must']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
                //echo "<p><strong>Location:</strong>&nbsp;<a href='".$results['Location']."' target='_blank'>".$results['SchoolLocation']."</a>".$results['text']."</p><br />";

                echo "<p><strong>Must:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Must']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
                echo "<p><strong>Can:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Can']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
                //echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Never']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
                echo  "<span id=\"nevermsg\"><p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Never']."".$results['text']."</p></span><br />";
                echo "<p><strong>_____________________________________________</strong>&nbsp;"."</p><br />";                
                echo "<p><strong>Tags:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Tags']."".$results['text']."</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following

    echo "<br /><br /><br /><strong><h2>"."You have searched a term that is not in the database. Please contact <a href=\"mailto:" . htmlentities('email@domain.com') . "\">".htmlentities('email@domain.com') . "</a>, if you think this term should be added."."</h2></strong>";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
<br />
    <br />
        <br />
            <br />
<br />
    <br />




</div>
<!--End of Inner Main-->
```

Additionally, here is a link to the site, where I've included a query in the URL [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/compliance_search.php?query=accredited).

Lastly, I call the stylesheet 'global.css', which is where the style lives.

```
#nevermsg { color: red; }
```

Comment: That can't possibly be valid PHP. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Never' (T_STRING), expecting ']'`

Comment: The top one is valid PHP. The bottom one, apparently is not.

Comment: @defaultNINJA - The code looks much nicer. However, the display on the HTML page is blank (for that line). Additionally, I'm not sure how buying a book on PHP coding would be productive. I don't use PHP too often. I'm just trying to style one line. I can't be the first person to style a PHP output string.

Comment: I'm lost. I understand all of this, but it only displays the word "Message" for output. It doesn't display the data from the database.

Comment: @webfrogs Then you need to post the your PHP code that makes the data base connection and the query.  My guess is that is where it is failing.

Comment: Is your question about the PHP syntax error, or the CSS "make it red" code?  If it's about PHP, clarify your question to focus on that, and *tag it PHP**.  If it's about the CSS, remove all the PHP and provide raw HTML and CSS which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: First you index your result array with 'Never' then with an html tagged 'Never'. What are u trying to do?

Comment: @defaultNINJA - Don't flag it please. I know you want to help. I'm going to post more code...

Comment: Ok. @defaultNINJA - I have added a bunch more code that might be able to help solve the problem.

Comment: @webfrogs Just a side note, not sure if it's the whole problem but `mysql_query` is depreciated you should be using `mysqli` extensions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php  Still looking at the code though.

Comment: Someone else mentioned that, too... on another issue. I have to work on moving the extensions over.

Comment: It's located in global.css. The id is #nevermsg. You can find it [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/css/global.css)

Comment: @defaultNINJA It's uploaded, but I am not seeing any changes. It doesn't appear to do anything. ** *Note to self - review associative arrays**

Comment: @webfrogs Do an `echo print_r($results);` this will print the entire results array and give you the `keys`.  My guess is your `keys` aren't right.

Comment: @webfrogs See update below for how to loop through the `$results` array.

Comment: Who would downvote this? This was a big problem on styling PHP output strings. I think this is useful and we solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the array type in your `while` loop.  [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) will return a standard array accessed like `$array[0]` not `$array['my_key']` so use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

So instead of this:

```
    while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
            echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;<span id=\"nevermsg\">".$results['Never']."</span></p>"; //Doesn't
    }
```

Do this:

```
    while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)) {
            echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;<span id=\"nevermsg\">".$results['Never']."</span></p>"; //Works
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

Another option if you don't know the `key` is loop through the `$results` array itself like so with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
    while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)) {
         foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
              echo "<span id=\"nevermsg\"><p><strong>$key:</strong>&nbsp;".$value."</p></span><br/>";
         }
    }
```

See the PHP fiddle example of the loop and `<span>` in action [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qm7-th8).  For obvious reasons the SQL could not be duplicated in the fiddle.

Comment: You may want to do a `echo print_r($results);` just see what the `key` and `value` is for each column being returned.  It's fairly easy to then tweak code from there if your `key` isn't right.

Comment: I did that. Curious about why you had me echo the question. Either way, it hasn't changed anything with styling the output of the "Never" line. You can re-review the link [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/compliance_search.php?query=accredited)

Comment: I added your update, but all it did was repeat the results. Now, it's displaying two sets of results. You can view [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/compliance_search.php?query=accredited)

Comment: @webfrogs that tells me that you don't need that second `key` out put.  I removed it... still doesn't explain the lack of data.  Have you done a `echo print_r($results);`?  That will tell you what your actually returning.  Do you mind just adding that line and I'll take a look at the output.

Comment: The query is fine. I'm returning the results I want. I just want this line `echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Never']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";` to return the results in the font color red.

Comment: See [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) documentation to see what we are trying to get.  Well it's not your query I'm concerned about, it's the `$results` array which is different.  If nothing is being populated, there is nothing to turn red.

Comment: And wrapping it in `<span>` will work.  See the fiddle [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qm7-th8) for a working example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34187/discussion-between-webfrogs-and-defaultninja)

Comment: @webfrogs It will have to wait till I'm off work.  My work place blocks the chat.  I'll be home in about an hour or two if no one has helped you out by then.

Comment: Ok. I'll wait for you. I'll be here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use direct output of HTML?

```
// some preceding PHP code
?>
<p>
  <strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="nevermsg"><?=$results['Never'].$results['text'] ?></span>
</p>
```

It will be more readable and there will be no mess of HTML and PHP quotes, and no need to escape them...

Comment: This isn't his problem as discovered in the comment threads.  His query doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The query works just fine. I want the output to display in the color red.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;" . $results['<div id=\"nevermsg\">\'Never\'</div>'] . $results['text'] . "</p><br />";
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all it did was hide the display of the output I'm trying to make red.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, it's your HTML which is quite messy. Try replacing this:

```
echo "<p><strong>Never:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['Never']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
```

With:

```
?>
<strong>Never:</strong>
<div id="nevermsg"><?= $results['Never']; ?></div>
<br>
<?php
```

Comment: I tried that and I got a server error... Page wouldn't even display.